# Laravel - restructuring array for easy sync of many-to-many with additional pivot data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have created what feels like a clunky solution to restructuring a data array in order to pass it to a sync() to update a many-to-many relationship with additional data in the pivot table and wondered if anyone could suggest a simpler approach.

I have an array coming from a request, here's a relevant extract:

```
"papers" => [
    0 => [
      "id" => 2
      "code" => "123-321-888"
      "name" => "Pop out"
      "pivot" => [
        "job_id" => 46
        "paper_id" => 2
        "qty_required" => 500
      ]
    ]
    1 => [
      "id" => 1
      "code" => "444-666-999"
      "name" => "Premium pro"
      "pivot" => [
        "job_id" => 46
        "paper_id" => 1
        "qty_required" => 1000
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

In order to do an easy sync of a many-to-many relationship with extra pivot data one needs to restructure that to:

```
[
 paper[id] => [ 
    'qty_required' => paper[pivot][qty_required] 
    ]
]
```

Which for the above example would be:

```
[
  2 => [
    "qty_required" => "500"
  ]
  1 => [
    "qty_required" => "1000"
  ]
]
```

I'm currently doing a 2-step process to achieve this as follows:

```
$paperUpdate = Arr::pluck($request->input('papers'), 'pivot.qty_required', 'id');
//output: [  2 => 500,  1 => 1000]

foreach ($paperUpdate as $key => $value) {
    $paperSync[$key]['qty_required'] = $value;
}

//output: [ 2 => [ "qty_required" => "500" ],  1 => [ "qty_required" => "1000" ]

$job->papers()->sync($paperSync);
```

Is there an easier approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems fine to me. If you want to nit pick, you could do one less iteration using:

```
$sync = array_reduce($request->input('papers'), function ($sync, $paper) {
    $id = $paper['id'];
    $sync[$id] = [ 'qty_required' => $paper['pivot']['qty_required'] ];

    return $sync;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know I'm not doing anything foolish! Will have a look at array_reduce.